# Migrate my Bluetooth device pairings to a different Mac

Tags: bluetooth, migration

*Context:* I am in the process of migrating from an old MBP (10.6.8) to a newer MBR (10.9). This is not an in-place upgrade or Time Machine restore; it is a manual migration to new hardware, new OS, new disk partitioning, and new user accounts.

*Specifics*: My old MBP has a significant number of saved/remembered Bluetooth devices that it has paired with in various times and places. **I would like to find a way to export these settings from my old MBP and then import them to my new MBR.** I do *not* want to have to go through the manual pairing process for every device again. (yuk!)

- The more automated the process is, the better.
- The more general the process is, the better. (Both for my own future migrations and for others.)
- If there's a way to see these settings in plaintext, extra points because it's a learning opportunity!

Comment: Off topic, but I was able to do this same kind of migration for my saved wifi passwords using `security`, the command-line keychain utility, along with a bit of shell scripting.

Comment: Bluetooth Explorer app (in 10.6.8) doesn't seem to help; you can *see* tons of info about cached connections, but I can't find a way to export it. I'm now mining through various .plist files.